# How to find with regex and match by pattern after last slash

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, find

On Linux server I have several files in folder and my question is:

How to find with regex only filename(s), started with **foo** or **bar** and ended with **.properties**. But not **any.properties**. Only **foo**-service **.properties** and **bar**-service **.properties**

```
/home/user/foo-service/src/main/resources/any.properties

/home/user/foo-service/src/main/resources/foo-service.properties

/home/user/foo-service/src/main/resources/bar-service.properties
```

Try to find with string:

```bash
find /home/user/foo-service/src/main/resources/ -maxdepth 1 \
-regextype posix-extended  -regex .*(foo|bar).*\.properties
```

but in result I have all 3 strings, because *foo* exists in the path (*/foo-service/*)

I want to find only after the last slash in the path and as a result I need **absolute** path to the file.

Comment: OP knows very well how to use `-regex` option in `find`. Issue is in the regex pattern not in the command.

Comment: You have forgotten to quote your patterns. What is confusing, is that your `find` statement should produce an error, because the `|` is interpreted as pipe symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this command:

```bash
find /home/user/foo-service/src/main/resources/ -maxdepth 1 \
  -regextype posix-extended  -regex '.*/(foo|bar)[^/]*\.properties$'
```

Here, `(foo|bar)[^/]*\.properties$` will match any file name that starts with `foo` or `bar` and ends with `.properties` while matching 0 or more of any char that is not `/` after `foo` or `bar`.

So this will match:

```
/home/user/foo-service/src/main/resources/foo-service.properties
/home/user/foo-service/src/main/resources/bar-service.properties
```

but won't match:

```
/home/user/foo-service/src/main/resources/any.properties
```

Since we have a `/` character after `/foo` in last path.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `-name` option instead to match just the base file name rather than having to deal with the entire path name. Use the `-o` operator to match both prefixes:

```
find /home/user/foo-service/src/main/resources/ -maxdepth 1 \
    \( -name 'foo*.properties' -o -name 'bar*.properties' \)
```

Comment: Yes. I tried, but it doesn't good for me because I take regex  from external json (I do this in the pipeline in groovy and read regex from json file)